# Installing wakanda server on arch linux

Tags: linux, wakanda

Is there any way to install wakanda server on manjaro linux (based on arch linux, package manager:pacman) and use it as a service?
Actually the only choice is to install it on ubuntu.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Wakanda is only supported for Ubuntu. Meaning that it is not tested or package for other linux platforms.

You can extract the DEB package using `ar` command.

```
$ ar -x ./test_2.0.0_amd64.deb
tar -xzf data.tar.gz
```

Here an example how to extract DEB package. http://blog.packagecloud.io/eng/2015/10/13/inspect-extract-contents-debian-packages/